# Ugly inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, coding-style

I have

```
public class ViewBaseBase : UserControl
```

Then I have

```
public class ViewBase<TPresenter, TIView> : ViewBaseBase
```

Which leads of course to

```
public class AView : ViewBase<ConcretePresenter, IView>
```

The reasoning goes, I'd like a non generic way to access ViewBase polymorphically without knowing TPresenter, TIView.

Does this look "wrong" to anyone? I don't know, it works, it doesn't seem to be causing me problems, but it feels "wrong" some how. Possibly it's the ViewBaseBase name, I could probably use an interface instead, but actually I quite like having the UserControl inheritance at that level as all ViewBase must be a UserControl...

Comment: Its hard to say without knowing what ViewBaseBase and ViewBase do. I rarely use inheritance, and have never found it all that useful in my application code (libraries, support facilities are another story).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much you can do unless you have a non-generic absolute base class, if you wish to access this stuff polymorphically.  You've also said that every `ViewBase` must be a UserControl, but that doesn't mean you can't use interfaces.  Consider this:

```
public interface IViewBase
{
}


public abstract class ViewBase<IPresneter, TIView> : UserControl
                                                   , IViewBase
{
}


public class AView : ViewBase<ConcretePresenter, IView>
{
}
```

AView is now a `UserControl` and a `IViewBase`.  I personally think this is cleaner.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I've moved to. It's nice to get confirmation or at least a bit of back up that I'm not going nuts :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ViewBaseBase : UserControl
```

If any ViewBaseBase must be a UserControl, then this is preferable to an interface because it enforces this.
If ViewBaseBase provides code rather than just signatures (everything is abstract), then this is the only possible way to do things without some really heavy convolutions, because C# doesn't provide multiple inheritance.
If ViewBaseBase only provides signatures (everything is abstract) and something could conceivably be a ViewBaseBase without being a UserControl (even if not in your project), then I'd consider an interface.

Much the same logic comes at the subsequent levels of the hierarchy.

On the overall hierarchy, is it getting in your way in any case? If it is then it may be worth refactoring in one way or another, but if it isn't then I wouldn't even pause to think about it. After all, the purpose of the class hierarchy is to make the developers' lives easier, so whether or not it is doing that is the ultimate concern.

Comment: No it wasn't in the way, it works perfectly. One of the advantages it had before I refactored it to an interface was differing access levels on the member properties of ViewBaseBase. Nothing that derives from ViewBaseBase should ever not be a usercontrol. It just felt "wrong". I have to keep putting it in quotes because it was a hunch, gut feel rather than anything solid

Comment: I'd favour sticking with what you had then. It seems - from what I understand of what you are doing - to be what most closely models your intention, which is the whole point of programming in high-level languages. Moving away from that without good reason feels a lot more wrong to me.